# Support v7 GridLayout doesn't stretch columns

Tags: android, grid-layout, android-support-library, android-gridlayout

I'm trying to use GridLayout from support library in my project. All that I've done was adding it to my project as Android library. I've created a simple layout to show what is not workning.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.myapp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin"
    app:columnCount="3"
    app:rowCount="8"
    tools:context=".RegistrationActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/activity_registration_company"
        app:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/activity_registration_street"
        app:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:text="2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/activity_registration_building"
        app:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:text="3" />
</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

And here is what I see in Eclipse layout editor (the same on device):
[image]

As you can see GridLayout's content doesn't occupy the whole width. Also Button doesn't occupy the space defined by spans. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use
`android:layout_columnWeight="X"` (X is any number you want it to be) with `android:layout:width="0dp"`